# The definition of the line bundle $E^k\to P_1(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

[image]

Here is an example from the book of differential analysis on compact manifold.
But I feel confused with using the transition function $g_{0,1}^k$ to define the line bundle $E^k\to P_1(\mathbb{C})$. Can anyone explain about this?

Here $U_{r,n}$ is the disjoint union of the $r$-planes ($r$-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-linear subspaces) in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: «the book of differential analysis on compact manifold»? The idea there is only onebook and we know about which you are talking about is weird. Please provide complete references to books and papers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If vector bundles $E$ and $F$ have transition functions $g_{\alpha\beta}$ and $h_{\alpha\beta}$, then $E\otimes F$ has transition functions $g_{\alpha\beta}h_{\alpha\beta}$. Therefore the bundle $E^k$ has transition functions $g^k_{\alpha\beta}.$

And to see why the transition functions for the tautological line bundle $E$ are what they are, let $(\ell,v)$ be a point in $E$. So $v\in\ell.$ In homogeneous coordinates, $\ell=[z_0,z_1]$ is a line in $\mathbb{C}^2$ spanned by the vector $(z_0,z_1).$ So $v=k(z_0,z_1)$ for some $k\neq 0.$

So in the affine patch $U_1 = \{[z_0,z_1]|z_0\neq0\},$ with coordinate $z=z_1/z_0$ we have a nowhere vanishing section $e_1\colon\ell\mapsto (1,z)$, so $v=kz_0e_1$ in the induced trivialization. And in affine patch $U_1 = \{[z_0,z_1]|z_1\neq0\},$ with coordinate $w=z_0/z_1$, our non-vanishing section is $e_2\colon\ell\mapsto (w,1).$ Under this trivialization, we have $v=kz_1e_2.$ Thus the transition from the $U_0$ to the $U_1$, the transition function is $(z_0/z_1)$.

So $E^k$ has transition functions $(z_0/z_1)^k.$